# Why I'm getting NULL on WHILE loop

Tags: php

I want get data from offers table ordered DESC by payout. If offer ID exist in offers_disabled_smart_link table, move to next and display link. What I'm doing wrong? I getting NULL when echo $link.

My DeliverService class is:

```
class DeliveryService {

    protected $user_id;
    protected $country;
    protected $os;
    protected $ip;
    protected $referrer;
    protected $token;
    protected $smart_link;

    public function __construct($user_id,$country,$ip,$os,$referrer,$token,$smart_link)
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
        $this->user_country = $country;
        $this->user_ip = $ip;
        $this->user_os = $os;
        $this->user_referrer = $referrer;
        $this->user_token = $token;
        $this->smart_link_id = $smart_link;
    }

    public function getStatusOfferSmartLink($offer_id,$smart_link_id,$user_id)

        {
            global $db;
            $sql="SELECT offer_id,smart_link_id,user_id FROM offers_disabled_smart_link WHERE smart_link_id=:smart_link_id AND offer_id=:offer_id and user_id=:user_id";
            $stmp = $db->prepare($sql);  
            $stmp->execute(array(":smart_link_id"=>$smart_link_id,":offer_id"=>$offer_id,":user_id"=>$user_id));
            $results = $stmp->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                if($results)
                return true;
            else return false;
        }

    public function deliver()
    {
        global $db;
        $sql="SELECT id, link, payout FROM offers ORDER BY payout DESC";
        $stmp = $db->prepare($sql);  
        $stmp->execute();
        while ($row = $stmp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {

                $id = $row['id'];
                $link = $row['link'];


        if($this->getStatusOfferSmartLink($id,$this->smart_link_id,$this->user_id)){
            continue;

        }

        break;
         $this->localFlag = true;


    }
    if ($this->localFlag) {

    return $link;

    }
}
```

Here I call function deliver() and echo $link

```
$ad = new DeliveryService(354,$country,$ip,$os,$referrer,$token,$smart_link);
    $link = $ad->deliver();

    echo $link;
```

If you want any informations, ask me.

Comment: Why set the localFlag after break? Wouldn't that break from the loop after the first iteration before the variable is set? And do use `closeCursor()` after a select query.

Comment: @frz3993 Thanks man, it was my mistake, is working now! Post as answer! And what about closeCursor() ?

Comment: It is to free the cursor so the statement can be executed again. Some people encountered problems getting data from the previous select query  when executing another select query. Probably db engine dependent, but better be safe though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume that your query return your expected data.

`$this->localFlag = true;` line will never execute as it's after `break` statement. (Assume that you didn't set `$this->localFlag` anywhere else.)

change this:

`break;`
`$this->localFlag = true;`

to:

`$this->localFlag = true;`
`break;`

and try. Hope it will work.